Issue with interpreting chemical formulae containing multiple levels of parentheses
I am working on a C program to interpret chemical formulae that may include multiple levels of parentheses, and I am facing difficulties with correctly interpreting these formulae. The goal is to associate each atom with a variable based on a provided formula.
I am using the code below to process chemical formulae with varying levels of complexity. For example, for the formula {"2F2(SO4)3", 'A'}, the processing is correct; however, for {"Na(H2(SO3)4)5", 'B'}, the interpretation is incorrect. The expected result for {"Na(H2(SO3)4)5", 'B'} should be Na + H10 + S20 + O60, but it is resulting in Na + H10 + S10 + O15, indicating that the processing of nested parentheses is not functioning as expected.
From what I observed, the logic is multiplying the innermost parenthesis by the factor of the outermost parenthesis. For example, in (H2(SO3)4)5, it is multiplying 'O3' by 5 instead of by 4 before then multiplying by 5.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    char symbol[3];  // Atom symbol (e.g., "H", "O")
} Atom;

typedef struct {
    char term[50];    // Formula term (e.g., "2H2O", "3CO2")
    char variable;    // Variable associated with the term
} Association;

void printVariableAtomTable(Atom *atoms, int numAtoms, Association *terms, int numTerms) {
    // Print table header
    printf("\nTable of Association between Variables and Elements:\n");
    printf("Variable: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numTerms; i++) {
        printf("%c  ", terms[i].variable);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Create matrix to store the quantity of each atom associated with each variable
    int **table = (int **)malloc(numAtoms * sizeof(int *));
    if (table == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate memory for table.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numAtoms; i++) {
        table[i] = (int *)calloc(numTerms, sizeof(int));
        if (table[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Error: Failed to allocate memory for table.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Fill the table with the quantity of each atom associated with each variable
    for (int j = 0; j < numTerms; j++) {
        char *term = terms[j].term;
        int termCoefficient = 1;
        int multiplier = 1;

        // Check if there is a numeric coefficient associated with the term (if any)
        char *coeffEnd = strchr(term, '(');
        if (coeffEnd != NULL) {
            sscanf(coeffEnd + 1, "%d", &termCoefficient);
        }

        int k = 0;
        while (term[k] != '\0') {
            if (isdigit(term[k])) {
                multiplier = term[k] - '0'; // Convert the numeric char to integer
                k++;
                continue;
            }

            if (isupper(term[k])) {
                char symbol[3] = { term[k], '\0' };
                int m = k + 1;
                while (term[m] != '\0' && islower(term[m])) {
                    strncat(symbol, &term[m], 1);
                    m++;
                }

                int elementCoefficient = 1;
                if (term[m] != '\0' && isdigit(term[m])) {
                    elementCoefficient = term[m] - '0';
                    m++;
                }

                int elementIndex = -1;
                for (int n = 0; n < numAtoms; n++) {
                    if (strcmp(atoms[n].symbol, symbol) == 0) {
                        elementIndex = n;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (elementIndex != -1) {
                    table[elementIndex][j] += elementCoefficient * multiplier * termCoefficient;
                }

                k = m;
            } else if (term[k] == '(') {
                // Start of a group within parentheses
                int start = k + 1;
                int depth = 1;
                int end = start;

                // Find the end of the group within parentheses
                while (term[end] != '\0' && depth > 0) {
                    if (term[end] == '(') {
                        depth++;
                    } else if (term[end] == ')') {
                        depth--;
                    }
                    end++;
                }

                // Process the group within parentheses
                int groupCoefficient = 1;
                if (term[end] != '\0' && isdigit(term[end])) {
                    sscanf(&term[end], "%d", &groupCoefficient);
                }

                int innerCoefficient = 1;
                int n = start;
                while (n < end) {
                    if (isupper(term[n])) {
                        char groupSymbol[3] = { term[n], '\0' };
                        int m = n + 1;
                        while (term[m] != '\0' && islower(term[m])) {
                            strncat(groupSymbol, &term[m], 1);
                            m++;
                        }

                        int groupIndex = -1;
                        for (int a = 0; a < numAtoms; a++) {
                            if (strcmp(atoms[a].symbol, groupSymbol) == 0) {
                                groupIndex = a;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (groupIndex != -1) {
                            if (term[m] != '\0' && isdigit(term[m])) {
                                sscanf(&term[m], "%d", &innerCoefficient);
                                while (term[m] != '\0' && isdigit(term[m])) {
                                    m++;
                                }
                            }
                            table[groupIndex][j] += termCoefficient * innerCoefficient * groupCoefficient * multiplier;
                        }

                        n = m;
                    } else {
                        n++;
                    }
                }

                k = end;
            } else {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the table of association between variables and elements
    for (int i = 0; i < numAtoms; i++) {
        printf("%s: ", atoms[i].symbol);
        for (int j = 0; j < numTerms; j++) {
            if (table[i][j] != 0) {
                if (table[i][j] == 1) {
                    printf("%c  ", terms[j].variable);
                } else {
                    printf("%d%c  ", table[i][j], terms[j].variable);
                }
            } else {
                printf("0%c  ", terms[j].variable);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Free allocated memory for the table
    for (int i = 0; i < numAtoms; i++) {
        free(table[i]);
    }
    free(table);
}

int main() {
    // Example input data (atoms and terms)
    Atom atoms[] = { {"F"}, {"O"}, {"S"}, {"H"}, {"Na"} };
    Association terms[] = { {"2F2(SO4)3", 'A'}, {"Na(H2(SO3)4)5", 'B'} };
    int numAtoms = sizeof(atoms) / sizeof(Atom);
    int numTerms = sizeof(terms) / sizeof(Association);

    // Function call
    printVariableAtomTable(atoms, numAtoms, terms, numTerms);

    return 0;
}

Result
Table of Association between Variables and Elements:
Variable: A  B  
F: 4A  0B  
O: 24A  15B  
S: 6A  10B  
H: 0A  10B  
Na: 0A  B  

How can I modify my code to correct the interpretation of formulae with multiple levels of parentheses?
Is there a more efficient way to handle the analysis of chemical formulae with varying complexity, including nested parentheses?
I appreciate any help or suggestions to solve this formula interpretation problem. Thank you!

Have you considered describing your formulas as a formal grammar, and then approach it with the regular parsing methods?

@EugeneSh. I've done what you suggested. This is another void ProcessForm function, and it handles nested parentheses groups very well. However, when I integrate it with the function that builds the table of variables, the table can't handle nested parentheses groups. So, I isolated printVariableAtomTable and created a minimal reproducible example.

To address the issue of interpreting chemical formulas with nested parentheses, I modified the original code to handle this complexity by utilizing a recursive approach to correctly process formulas. Below is the modified version of the code, which yields the expected results for examples like "Na(H2(SO3)4)5".
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    char symbol[3];  // Atom symbol (e.g., "H", "O")
} Atom;

typedef struct {
    char term[50];    // Formula term (e.g., "2H2O", "3CO2")
    char set;         // Unknown associated with the term
} Association;

void processChemicalFormula(char *formula, int coefficient, int table[][50], Atom *atoms, int numAtoms, int termIndex);

void printUnknownsTable(Atom *atoms, int numAtoms, Association *terms, int numTerms) {
    printf("\nAssociation Table between Unknowns and Elements:\n");
    printf("X: ");
    
    // Print header with unknowns
    for (int i = 0; i < numTerms; i++) {
        printf("%c  ", terms[i].set);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Create and initialize matrix to store quantities associated with each unknown
    int table[numAtoms][50];
    memset(table, 0, sizeof(table));

    // Fill the table with quantities of each atom associated with each unknown
    for (int j = 0; j < numTerms; j++) {
        processChemicalFormula(terms[j].term, 1, table, atoms, numAtoms, j);
    }

    // Print the elements associated with each atom for each unknown
    for (int i = 0; i < numAtoms; i++) {
        printf("%s: ", atoms[i].symbol);
        for (int j = 0; j < numTerms; j++) {
            if (table[i][j] != 0) {
                printf("%d%c  ", table[i][j], terms[j].set);
            } else {
                printf("0%c  ", terms[j].set);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Recursive function to process the chemical formula and fill the association table
void processChemicalFormula(char *formula, int coefficient, int table[][50], Atom *atoms, int numAtoms, int termIndex) {
    int len = strlen(formula);
    int i = 0;
    int termCoefficient = 1;  // Initialize term coefficient as 1 by default

    // Check if the first character of the formula is a digit
    if (isdigit(formula[i])) {
        // Use sscanf to read the coefficient from the current position (i)
        sscanf(&formula[i], "%d", &termCoefficient);

        // Update index (i) to move past the read coefficient
        while (isdigit(formula[i]) && i < len) {
            i++;
        }

        // Multiply termCoefficient by the total coefficient of the term
        termCoefficient *= coefficient;
    }

    while (i < len) {
        if (isalpha(formula[i])) {
            // Start of an atom symbol
            char symbol[3] = { formula[i], '\0' };
            i++;

            while (islower(formula[i]) && i < len) {
                strncat(symbol, &formula[i], 1);
                i++;
            }

            // Check if there's a numeric coefficient associated with the atom
            int atomCoefficient = 1;
            if (isdigit(formula[i])) {
                sscanf(&formula[i], "%d", &atomCoefficient);
                while (isdigit(formula[i]) && i < len) {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            // Find the index of the atom in the list of atoms
            int atomIndex = -1;
            for (int k = 0; k < numAtoms; k++) {
                if (strcmp(atoms[k].symbol, symbol) == 0) {
                    atomIndex = k;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Fill the table with the quantity of atoms associated with the term and unknown
            if (atomIndex != -1) {
                table[atomIndex][termIndex] += coefficient * termCoefficient * atomCoefficient;
            }
        } else if (formula[i] == '(') {
            // Start of a group within parentheses
            int j = i + 1;
            int depth = 1;

            // Find the end of the group within parentheses
            while (j < len && depth > 0) {
                if (formula[j] == '(') {
                    depth++;
                } else if (formula[j] == ')') {
                    depth--;
                }
                j++;
            }

            // Process the coefficient of the group within parentheses, if any
            int groupCoefficient = 1;
            if (j < len && isdigit(formula[j])) {
                sscanf(&formula[j], "%d", &groupCoefficient);
                while (isdigit(formula[j]) && j < len) {
                    j++;
                }
            }

            // Recursively process the group within parentheses
            processChemicalFormula(&formula[i+1], coefficient * termCoefficient * groupCoefficient, table, atoms, numAtoms, termIndex);
            i = j; // Update index to after the processed group
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Atom atoms[] = { {"F"}, {"O"}, {"S"}, {"H"}, {"Na"} };
    Association terms[] = { {"2F2(SO4)3", 'A'}, {"Na(H2(SO3)4)5", 'B'} };
    int numAtoms = sizeof(atoms) / sizeof(Atom);
    int numTerms = sizeof(terms) / sizeof(Association);

    printUnknownsTable(atoms, numAtoms, terms, numTerms);

    return 0;
}

Result:
Association Table between Unknowns and Elements:
Unknown: A  B  
F: 4A  0B  
O: 24A  60B  
S: 6A  20B  
H: 0A  10B  
Na: 0A  1B  


A big problem is the idea that we need to do everything at once.
Get past that. It is okay to break the problem down into simpler steps,
where each step just takes you closer to the desired result.
Let us look at the problem item:
    Na(H2(SO3)4)5
I will make a minor change (to illustrate something later):
    S2(H2(SO3)4)5
Vocabulary & Data Representation
In the following I will use the term “list“ to refer to whatever structure you use to keep track of parsed (element,count) values. Two good options that come to mind are an array (static will do) or a linked list (singly-linked suffices). Remember, the list must be ordered, you must be able to add an element to it, and index/traverse it.
⟶ I used a singly-linked list for my own implementation, but a static array is probably simplest.
Also, I am not too worried about representing the way the items in the list are stored. I’ll just write, e.g. O2 to represent an element value of "O" and a count value of 2. The way you store the elements is entirely up to you.
⟶ I converted the atomic symbol to it’s corresponding atomic number and stored it as an integer. This is probably overkill for your assignment, but was oh-so-easy and fun, and made dealing with it later so much simpler.
The Problem: Parentheses ⟶ Recursive Thinking
Let’s imagine walking the example problem:
// This is the list of elements we are collecting.
// It is COMMON to all invocations of the function!
// (You could make it a global variable, or just pass a
//  reference to it as argument to your parsing function.)
list = {}

Invoke your parsing function.

[invocation 0]
  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
   ↑ found Sulfur
  list = { S1 }
    Notice how we add BOTH the element AND an automatic count of 1 to the list?
    We can update that count as necessary.

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
    ↑ found a subscript
      this is where you update the count of the last item in the list
  list = { S2 }

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
      ↑ found an open parenthesis
        make note of how long your list is
        RECURSE on your parsing function to handle stuff inside
  list = { S2 }
               ↑0

[invocation 1]
  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
        ↑ found Hydrogen
  list = { S2, H1 }
               ↑0

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
         ↑ found subscript
           update last item
  list = { S2, H2 }
               ↑0

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
           ↑ found another open parenthesis
             make note of list length and recurse again
  list = { S2, H2 }
               ↑0  ↑1

[invocation 2]
  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
             ↑ found Sulfur
  list = { S2, H2, S1 }
               ↑0  ↑1

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
              ↑ (no subscript == do nothing)
  list = { S2, H2, S1 }
               ↑0  ↑1

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
               ↑ found Oxygen
  list = { S2, H2, S1, O1 }
               ↑0  ↑1

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
                ↑ found subscript
                  update last item
  list = { S2, H2, S1, O3 }
               ↑0  ↑1

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
                  ↑ found close parenthesis
                    return!
  list = { S2, H2, S1, O3 }
               ↑0  ↑1

[back to invocation 1]
  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
                    ↑ found subscript
                      update all elements STARTING at pre-recursion list length
  list = { S2, H2, S1, O3 }
               ↑0  ↑1
  list = { S2, H2, S1*4, O3 }
               ↑0  ↑1
  list = { S2, H2, S4, O3*4 }
               ↑0      ↑1
  list = { S2, H2, S4, O12 }
               ↑0
                
  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
                      ↑ found close parenthesis
                       return!
  list = { S2, H2, S4, O12 }
               ↑0

[back to invocation 0]
  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
                        ↑ found subscript
                          update all elements starting at pre-recursion list length
  list = { S2, H2, S4, O12 }
               ↑0
  list = { S2, H2*5, S4, O12 }
               ↑0
  list = { S2, H10, S4*5, O12 }
                    ↑0
  list = { S2, H10, S20, O12*5 }
                         ↑0
  list = { S2, H10, S20, O60 }

  "S2 ( H2 ( S O3 ) 4 ) 5"
                         ↑ end of input; all done!
  list = { S2, H10, S20, O60 }

The parsing function does not need to be written recursively. You could totally do an iterative version. That requires an additional list to track list length every time an open-parenthesis was found.
One more step
At this point you have a list that may contain duplicates!
Notably, however, we are significantly closer to the desired result: all the parenthetical stuff has been removed!
    S2 H10 S20 O60
Now all we need to do is combine like elements. There are at least two very obvious ways to do this, both very easy. Write another function to do it.
Main
All done, your main function should be very simple-looking:
int main()
{
  // s <-- ask user for chemical formula to parse
  char s[1000];
  {
    printf( "formula? " );
    fflush( stdout );
    fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin );
    char * p = strchr( s, '\n' );
    if (p) *p = '\0';
  }
  
  // here is the list of (element,count) pairs we will parse out of `s`
  #define MAX_LIST_SIZE 1000
  element list[MAX_LIST_SIZE];
  int size = 0;
  
  // first pass (recursive function that does the parentheses)
  parse_elements( s, list, &size, MAX_LIST_SIZE );
  
  // second pass (add duplicate elements)
  simplify_list( list, &size, MAX_LIST_SIZE );
  
  // now we can print out our list
  if (size)
  {
    printf( "%s%d", list[0].element, list[0].count );
    for (int n = 1;  n < size;  n++)
      printf( " + %s%d", list[0].element, list[0].count );
    printf( "\n" );
  }
}

